# Gulp Watch working on one sever but not the other

Tags: css, gulp, centos6, gulp-watch

I am having trouble getting gulp watch to work properly on two different servers.  The first server is with Linode running Ubuntu 14.04 and everything is working fine.  The second server is with MediaTemple and running CentOS 6.  This is the server I'm having a problem with.

If I run my sass compilation task, the sass files will compile to the correct style.css file.  However, when I run gulp watch, the sass file compiles into an empty style.css file.

Both servers are using the same package.json file and the same gulpfile.js.

Would the difference in operation systems be causing this?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
David

gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';
require("time-require");

/**************************************************************
enter
  gulpt build --sorted
in terminal to see why gulp is loading slow.
***************************************************************/

//General Plugins
  var gulp = require('gulp');
  var livereload = require( 'gulp-livereload' );
  var del = require('del');
  var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

//SASS Plugins
  var sass = require('gulp-sass');
  var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

//JS Plugins
  var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');


/**************************************************************
  Cleaning Up Files
***************************************************************/

gulp.task('clean', function() {
  del('./*.css');
});

/**************************************************************
  Gulp SASS Compilation
***************************************************************/

gulp.task('sassy', function() {
  return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'}).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});

/**************************************************************
  JS Hinting & Minification(later) Compilation
***************************************************************/

gulp.task('jshint', function() {
  return gulp.src('./js/scripts.js')
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});

/**************************************************************
  NSA'ing all your files
***************************************************************/
gulp.task('watch', ['sassy'], function() {

  livereload.listen({host:'205.186.140.200', port : '35729'});

  //watch sassy files
  gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sassy']).on('change', function(event) {
      console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...');
    });

  //watch scripts.js
  gulp.watch('./js/scripts.js', ['jshint']).on('change', function(event) {
      console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...');
    });

  //watch all php files
  gulp.watch('./**/*.php' ).on( 'change', function( file ) {
    livereload.changed( file );
  });

});
```

Comment: Just to double check, do both servers have the same file/folder structure and are all .scss files present on both?

Comment: Yes, both have the same structure.  They are both Wordpress installs.  The package.json file and the gulpfile.js are in the theme directory.  All sass files are in a directory called sass and all the files inside that directory have an extension of .scss